# Overlapping Histograms in R

Tags: r, histogram

I am overlapping two histograms, and would like to maintain each of them that are not in common, as well as the common area. (3 colors). I have the following codes:

```
 hotel_auto<-subset(hotel_pr_curr,hotel_pr_curr$BFR_CONDITION_1 =="AUTO_BFR")
 hotel_nonauto<-subset(hotel_pr_curr,hotel_pr_curr$BFR_CONDITION_1 == "NON_AUTO_BFR")

 hist_curr1<- hist(hotel_auto$CURR_DIF_RTO, breaks = 20)
 hist_curr2<- hist(hotel_nonauto$CURR_DIF_RTO, breaks = 20)

 hist_curr1$density<-hist_curr1$counts/sum(hist_curr1$counts)*100
 hist_curr2$density<-hist_curr2$counts/sum(hist_curr2$counts)*100
  plot(hist_curr1,freq=FALSE,xlim=c(0,0.8),ylim=c(0,50),ylab="Percentage",col=rgb(0,0,1,1), main="BFR Current-Historical",xlab="Current Historical Difference")

  plot(hist_curr2,freq=FALSE,xlim=c(0,0.8),ylim=c(0,50),ylab="Percentage",col=rgb(1,0.9,0,1), main="",xlab="", add = TRUE)
  legend("topright", c("AUTO_BFR", "NONAUTO_BFR"), cex=0.75, fill=c("blue", "yellow"))
```

[image]

And it just has two colors, can I have three colors of them as I just mentioned? 
Thanks!

Comment: You could try changing `col=rgb(0,0,1,1)` to `col=rgb(0,0,1,0.5)`, where the last value in `rgb` is alpha. Edit, if you have 3 colours, then change the last value for each colour to 0.33.

Comment: That is great! Thanks!

Comment: @Swarch You could publish your comment as a solution, for the records!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last alpha value in `rgb` is for alpha, so if you change your colours to `col=rgb(0,0,1,0.5)` and `col=rgb(1,0.9,0,0.5)` you should be able to see the overlap.